# Add character between words in a string

Tags: string, go

Here is some sample code of what I want to achieve

```
var names string
names = "Adam Eve Noah"

//Unknown code here 

fmt.Println(names) // Output required is "Adam-Eve-Noah"
```

Comment: So, you want to replace each space character in a string with another character? If yes, the task is trivial, and can be dealt with using multitude of ways. Can you be more precise about the task? I'm asking because _"add_ character between words in a string" 1) contradicts the exampe; 2) is moot because words can be separated using any amount of whitespace, consisting of different whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ReplaceAll method from strings library

```
package main
  
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var names string
    names = "Adam Eve Noah"
    names = strings.ReplaceAll(names," ", "-")
    fmt.Println(names)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after implementing it in my code with some different string values, it works perfectly, have you got any resources for future reference on strings commands, because I had no idea this even existed

Comment: You might want to start with the documentation for the strings package: https://pkg.go.dev/strings